# Is it OK to re-try a less ambitious version of an overambitious edit?

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette, suggested-edits

My suggested edit https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/719881 was recently rejected.  My original intent was only to convert a link to a PDF article into a link to the abstract for that article.  I believe that the community consensus is that this is desireable.

However, while I was in there, I thought that I'd clean up the wording a little.  I felt that the edits were minor, but two of the reviewers felt that my suggestion deviated from the original intent of the post.

Oh, well; this is how I learn community norms, and I don't have a problem with it.  My question is whether it is OK to recommend again the part of the edit about converting the PDF link to an abstract link (and leave the wording alone).

Comment: Does the downvote mean "no, you shouldn't re-try the edit", or "you shouldn't have asked this Meta question"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is is fine to re-try. You intend to actually change the suggested-edit following the feedback received. Thus, I do not see why you should not do this.

To submit the very same suggestion would be a different matter, could be considered poor form, and likely should be reserved as response to egregiously poor reviews. (While I actually would have approved your original proposal, I can see where the reviewers are coming from, so it is not such a case.)